# How to form clusters when features are sets of string objects

Tags: classification, clustering, jaccard-similarity

I am building a movie recommender. But unlike common recommender from movielens data, features of my movies are sets like actor list, genre list, list of producers and writers etc.

I know I can use Jaccard similarity to find similarity of 2 movies on one feature but I cant figure out how to combine these features to find similarities.

I have a thought of taking the weighted sums of features' similarity for final similarity but I cant figure out how to learn the weights.

How can I form clusters of movies? How can one improve or find a way around the suggested method above?

Answer (score 3):

Primarily you would need to convert your strings into dummy variables and then compute a distance measure between rows.

The simplest of the techniques is "overlap" where you count how many common attributes are observed between a pair.

An improved version of this "goodall" weights the distance based on how infrequent a set of attributes are seen to be common.

A more exhaustive list can be seen here: [Similarity Measures for Categorical Data: A Comparative Evaluation](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~sboriah/PDFs/BoriahBCK2008.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way in which I dont need to make dummy vectors? because 4 features with 1680 movies can make 6720 dummy features

Comment: You are out of luck there. String in themselves have no meaning.

Comment: get_dummies function of pandas work on dataframes in which cells have strings...but I have list of strings in my cells. Can you help with that also?That would be alot of help :-)

Comment: If you use sparse vectors for the dummy variables, the number of features shouldn't matter much.